# Jekyll recompiles every page every time

Tags: jekyll

When I run `jekyll` to generate my site, it regenerates every page.  How do I tell it to generate only pages which are new or have changed?

Alternatly, what am I doing to make Jekyll think it need to recreate every page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jekyll automatically regenerates the entire site each time it runs -- that's just how it works. However, I believe it will only regenerate changed files if you pass the flag:

```
--watch
```

as in:

```
jekyll build --watch
```

---

*Note: Instead of `jekyll build --watch`, older versions of jekyll use `jekyll --auto`.*

Comment: To expand on this, the reason it re-generates *all* files by default is that some "unchanged" files may end up with old links, and/or your pagination (on your blog index) could be off.

Comment: How big can the site get before this breaks down?

Comment: `--auto` has been renamed to `--watch` in 1.0+

Comment: I would rather have broken links than wait minutes to generate.

Answer (score 2):

As mipadi said, Jekyll regenerates the entire site when compiling it. However, the `--auto` flag makes it compile the whole thing, *always*.

It does this because, as elithrar said, each post/page can depend on one another and, as it's all decided during compile time, it can't be generated on the fly like it would in WordPress or Tumblr. So, to avoid broken links, everything is regenerated.

This can be problematic on the long run. For example, very big sites (>1000 posts) report extremely long compiling times with LSI enabled, which was addressed with some configuration options lately. And there are other problems, i.e. if you're dealing with CSS/JS (or LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript, be my guest), why would you recreate the whole thing?

This is a recurring discussion on [Jekyll's issue list](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues), so if you guys can think of a good solution, please post it there.

But, sincerely? If your site is small enough, just let it regenerate everything. It's much simpler this way.

Answer (score 1):

For speeding up local development you can use `--limit_posts NUM` to limit the number of posts to parse. This can lead to significant time saving for sites with a lot of posts.

See
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#build-command-options